# Python BeautifulSoup TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have following

`li class = 'EntityList-item EntityList-item--Regular EntityList-item--n1  bp-radix__faux-anchor'`

I am trying to export all li classes, but the n1 part is changing to n2,n3 ... n100
Tried to do it this way :

```
url = 'https://www.xxxx.com' # just a random website
result = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')    
doc


x = 1
for add in doc:
    add.find('li', class_ = f'EntityList-item EntityList-item--Regular EntityList-item--n{x} bp-radix__faux-anchor')
    x += 1
    print(add)
```

But I am getting the error message:
TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments

any suggestion on how to loop through the above class, to export all elements, till x reaches 100.

Comment: Looks like you're calling the built-in string method `find()`, not the beautiful soup method.

Comment: @John Gordon I edited my question, as initially maybe it was clear enough, hope now it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre calling built-in function find and not soup.
you need to do:

```
soup.find('li', class_ = f'EntityList-item EntityList-item--Regular EntityList-item--n{x} bp-radix__faux-anchor')
```

to find them all try use findAll without a loop:

```
soup.findAll('li', class_ = f'EntityList-item EntityList-item--Regular EntityList-item--n{x} bp-radix__faux-anchor')
```

i found your problem:

```
url = 'https://www.xxxx.com' # just a random website
result = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')    
doc

for i in range(101):
    print(soup.find('li', class_ = f'EntityList-item EntityList-item--Regular EntityList-item--n{i} bp-radix__faux-anchor'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and how would I loop through that if I had an x range of 100?

Comment: please explain more @hello543

Comment: each <li class> has its own n{x} number from n1 to n100. So I would like to get all <li class>'es from n1 EntityList-item EntityList-item--Regular EntityList-item--n1  bp-radix__faux-anchor -> to n100-> EntityList-item EntityList-item--Regular EntityList-item--n100 bp-radix__faux-anchor

Comment: I edited my question, maybe now it makes more sense

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if it helped

Comment: Unfortunately no, it gives only for the defined x, so if I define x = 1, it would give only for n1, but I need from n1 to n100 that class.

Comment: try now, i found your problem